# Retrieve nested results with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse some nmap XML to retrieve various values via Nokogiri, but having quite a time figuring out recursion.  What I want is to grab the `ip_address` and any `port` element that has a child element of `status='open'`.  I want to be able to put each group into a JSON object to save into a database column for later display:

So far, here's my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'

doc = File.open("network_ports.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

doc.xpath('//host').each do |host|
  @ip_address = host.at_xpath("address[@addrtype='ipv4']").at_xpath("@addr").value
  puts "Found Host: #{@ip_address}"
  host.xpath('ports/port').each do |port|    
    if port.at_xpath("state[@state='open']")
      puts port.at_xpath("port[@portid]").value
    end
  end
end
```

However my output is broken right now with the following error:

```
port_parser.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Some same input from the file:

```
<host starttime="1501187906" endtime="1501189103"><status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="eclipse" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="996">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="996"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="53"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="domain" product="dnsmasq" version="2.45" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:thekelleys:dnsmasq:2.45</cpe></service></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"><state state="filtered" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="http" product="DD-WRT milli_httpd" hostname="eclipse" method="probed" conf="10"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="https" tunnel="ssl" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="2222"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" product="Dropbear sshd" version="0.52" extrainfo="protocol 2.0" ostype="Linux" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:matt_johnston:dropbear_ssh_server:0.52</cpe><cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel</cpe></service></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="4727" rttvar="1840" to="100000"/>
</host>
```

Am I running into an issue because I'm dependent on the nested `state` element within the `port` element which I need to be able to get the `portid` attribute value out of?

In the end, I'm just hoping for some output like:

```
Found host: 10.10.10.1
    port 22/tcp open
    port 23/tcp open
Found host: 10.10.10.2
    port 443/tcp open
    port 5432/tcp open
etc...
```

If you have any suggestions on cleaning up the code, I'm all ears as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything with your code seems to be working fine, except for

```
puts port.at_xpath("port[@portid]").value
```

you're already at the `port` element, so you just need the xpath `@portid`

```
puts port.at_xpath("@portid").value
```

and, with your example **network_ports.xml**, that outputs

```
# Found Host: 10.10.10.1
# 53
# 443
# 2222
```

Comment: Ah, that's my problem!  So the regression from the child `state` element wasn't a problem at all!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the [NMAP gem](https://github.com/sophsec/ruby-nmap)?

```
require 'nmap/xml'

Nmap::XML.new('scan.xml') do |xml|
  xml.each_host do |host|
    puts "[#{host.ip}]"

    host.each_port do |port|
      puts "  #{port.number}/#{port.protocol}\t#{port.state}\t#{port.service}"
    end
  end
end
```